# JFrame won't load new JFrame when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

So i have this project I'm working on where the user will get to choose between 5 games. Whenever I click on a button to play that game it wont load the game. Please help thanks in advance!

Main JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class JavaGames extends JFrame 
{
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    public static int height;
    public static int width;
    private JTextField test;
    private JButton BrickBreaker;
    private JButton Exit;
    private JButton Trapped;
    private JButton PacMan;
    private JButton PinBall;
    private JButton Pong;
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public JavaGames() throws IOException
    {
        this.setTitle("Application Project");
        this.setSize(449,350);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        height = screenSize.height;
        width = screenSize.width;
        generateMenu();
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        contentPane = new JPanel(null);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(192,192,192));
        BrickBreaker = new JButton();
        BrickBreaker.setBounds(108,69,95,35);
        BrickBreaker.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        BrickBreaker.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        BrickBreaker.setEnabled(true);
        BrickBreaker.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",0,11));
        BrickBreaker.setText("Brick Breaker");
        BrickBreaker.setVisible(true);
        BrickBreaker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               BrickBreaker(evt);
            }
        });
        Exit = new JButton();
        Exit.setBounds(219,175,95,35);
        Exit.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        Exit.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        Exit.setEnabled(true);
        Exit.setFont(new Font("sansserif",0,12));
        Exit.setText("Exit");
        Exit.setVisible(true);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Exit(evt);
            }
        });
        Trapped = new JButton();
        Trapped.setBounds(219,69,95,35);
        Trapped.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        Trapped.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        Trapped.setEnabled(true);
        Trapped.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",0,12));
        Trapped.setText("Trapped");
        Trapped.setVisible(true);
        Trapped.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Trapped(evt);
            }
        });
        PacMan = new JButton();
        PacMan.setBounds(219,120,95,35);
        PacMan.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        PacMan.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        PacMan.setEnabled(true);
        PacMan.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",0,11));
        PacMan.setText("Pac Man Demo");
        PacMan.setVisible(true);
        PacMan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                PacMan(evt);
            }
        });
        PinBall = new JButton();
        PinBall.setBounds(108,175,95,35);
        PinBall.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        PinBall.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        PinBall.setEnabled(true);
        PinBall.setFont(new Font("sansserif",0,12));
        PinBall.setText("Pin Ball");
        PinBall.setVisible(true);
        PinBall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                try{
                PinBall(evt);
                }catch( IOException io ) {}
            }
        });
        Pong = new JButton();
        Pong.setBounds(108,120,95,35);
        Pong.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
        Pong.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        Pong.setEnabled(true);
        Pong.setFont(new Font("sansserif",0,12));
        Pong.setText("Pong");
        Pong.setVisible(true);
        Pong.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Pong(evt);
            }
        });
        textfield1 = new JTextField();
        textfield1.setBounds(160,12,100,49);
        textfield1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        textfield1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        textfield1.setEnabled(false);
        textfield1.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",0,18));
        textfield1.setText("Welcome!");
        textfield1.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(BrickBreaker);
        contentPane.add(Exit);
        contentPane.add(Trapped);
        contentPane.add(PacMan);
        contentPane.add(PinBall);
        contentPane.add(Pong);
        contentPane.add(textfield1);
        this.add(contentPane);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);  
    }
    public static String[] q = new String[1];
    private void BrickBreaker(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        BrickGUI temp = new BrickGUI();
        temp.main(q);
    }
    private void Exit (ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        int n=0;
        System.exit(n);
    }
    private void Trapped(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        TrappedGUI run = new TrappedGUI();
        run.main(q);
    }
    private void PacMan (ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        PacManGUI run = new PacManGUI();
        run.main(q);
    }
    private void PinBall (ActionEvent evt) throws IOException
    {
        PinBallGUI run = new PinBallGUI();
        run.main(q);
    }
    private void Pong (ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        PongGUI run = new PongGUI();
        run.main(q);
    }
    public void generateMenu()
    {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenuItem openHS = new JMenuItem("High Scores");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        file.add(openHS);
        file.add(save);
        file.add(about);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(exit);
        menuBar.add(file);
        openHS.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                //HighScores run = new HighScores();
               //run.main(q);
            }
        });
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
               int n = 0;
               System.exit(n);
            }
        });        
        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                //about action
            }
        });  
     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf",      "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                new JavaGames();
                }catch( IOException io ) {}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

JFrame class to load the game:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BrickGUI extends JFrame
{
    public BrickGUI() 
    {
        BrickGame gui = new BrickGame();
        this.setSize(600,600+20);
        this.setTitle("Brick Breaker");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(new BrickGame());
        this.add(gui);
        gui.init(600,600);
        gui.start();
        gui.run();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new BrickGUI();  
    }
}
```

Class where the game is drawn and such:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class BrickGame extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener
{    
    Thread runner; 
    private Image Buffer;
    private Graphics gBuffer;
    private char c = 'e';
    int width,height;
    BrickBall B1;
    ArrayList BrickBallList;
    BrickBall temp,temp2;
    ArrayList bricks;
    BrickRectangle rTemp;
    int bx,by,bw,bh;
    BrickRectangle R1,R2;
    boolean leftKey;
    boolean rightKey;
    boolean spaceKey;
    Paddle p;
    int points;
    public void init(int W,int H)
   {  
        width=590;
        height=590;
        Buffer=createImage(width,height);
        gBuffer=Buffer.getGraphics();
        B1 = new BrickBall(-1);
        p = new Paddle();
        bricks = new ArrayList();
        bx = 5;
        by = 5;
        bw = 20;
        bh = 10;
        int count = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 160;i++)
       {
           rTemp = new BrickRectangle(bx,by,bw,bh,0,0);
           bx = bx + 25;
           count++;
           if(count == 32)
           {
               by = by + 15;
               bx = 5;
               count = 0;
           }
        bricks.add(rTemp);
    }
    addKeyListener(this);
    points = 0;
}
public void start()
{ 
    if (runner == null)
    {   
        runner = new Thread (this);
        runner.start();
    }
}
public void stop()
{  
    runner = null;
}
public void run() 
{  
    while(true)
    {
        if(rightKey){p.moveRight();}
        if(leftKey){p.moveLeft();}
        repaint();
        try {runner.sleep(25);}
        catch (Exception e) { }    
        gBuffer.setColor(Color.black);
        gBuffer.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        B1.moveBrickBall(width,height);
        p.ballCollision(B1);
        for(int j = 0; j < bricks.size();j++)
        {
             rTemp = (BrickRectangle)bricks.get(j);
             if(rTemp.BrickBallCollision(B1))
             {
                 bricks.remove(j);
                 points = points + 1;
                 break;
             }
        }
        String P = String.valueOf(points);
        gBuffer.setColor(Color.blue);
        gBuffer.setFont(new Font("Calibri",20,60));
        gBuffer.drawString(P,0,540);
        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.size();i++)
        {
            rTemp = (BrickRectangle)bricks.get(i);
            rTemp.paint(gBuffer);
        }
        B1.paint(gBuffer);
        p.paint(gBuffer);
        if(B1.getY()>height)
        {
            String s1 = "Game Over";
            String s2 = "You Lose!";
            String s3 = "You got " +points +" Points";
            String s4 = "Hit space key to continue";
            gBuffer.drawString(s1,50,90);
            gBuffer.drawString(s2,50,160);
            gBuffer.drawString(s3,50,230);
            gBuffer.setFont(new Font("Calibri",20,50));
            gBuffer.drawString(s4,50,300);
            BrickHS temp = new BrickHS();
            try{
                boolean t = temp.checkHS(points);
                if(t)
                {
                    gBuffer.drawString("New High Score",50,360);
                }
            }catch( IOException io ) {}
            if(spaceKey){System.exit(1);}
        }
        repaint();
    }//while(true)
} //run    
public void update(Graphics g)
{  
    paint(g);
} 
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(Buffer,0,0, this);
}
public void addNotify() 
{
    super.addNotify();
    requestFocus();
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
       {
           case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
           leftKey = true;
           break;
           case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
           rightKey = true;
           break;
           case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
           spaceKey = true;
           break;
       }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
       {
           case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
           leftKey = false;
           break;
           case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
           rightKey = false;
           break;
           case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
           spaceKey = false;
           break;
        }
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{
    c = e.getKeyChar();
    repaint();
}
}
```

There is also a few other classes that go with this game but those are mainly just to make the objects and what not. Again thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't run a game from the thread that invokes an event handler.  Don't use the same name for a variable and a method. Don't use names starting with an upper class letter for variables. Don't call a static method in some class via an object of that class.

Comment: That is a *lot* of code to ask volunteers to swim through - you might consider trimming it down to only the pieces that reproduce the issue you experience (eg an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a BrickGame is created, it enters into an infinite while loop by calling `run` - this is occurring on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and leads to a frozen user interface as the EDT cannot paint, create events, etc... Your code starts a new thread by calling `start` - there is no reason for the additional call to `run`.

Some other pieces of advice:

1. Override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`
2. Call `super.paintComponent` as one of the first calls within the implementation in (1)
3. You should not override `update`, nor `addNotify`
4. Setting the reference of Thread to `null` will not stop the Thread - instead, use a flag which cases the while loop to terminate (this flag may need to be declared volatile).
5. Variable names should start with a lower case letter.
6. Avoid `null` layouts - use an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I took out when it calls run and it works now! thanks so much for the advice and your help

Comment: @Zackc95 Glad to hear it, but please don't forget to take the rest of the advice seriously - they can cause headaches beyond comparison to this one.